# Present view controller that is already visible using iOS 7 transitions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I need to have one UIViewController's view visible on screen and part of another UIViewController's view visible above the first one. When needed, the second view should be maximised so that it covers most part of the first view.

How can I achieve this, preferably using iOS 7 interactive transitions (being able to drag the presented view), and keeping the two views managed by separate view controllers (not just stuffing both views into the same view controller)?

Here's a mockup to make things clearer:

[image: initial view state]
[image: presented view]

Comment: What I would do is on the first view, the "presented view controller" should be a dummy image, which can be a screenshot of the actual 2nd view if needed. Then on click you can do an interactive transition to the second view from this one. http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/

Comment: Since PresentedViewController is always visible (albeit partially) I'd probably just write a custom view controller container with the MainViewController and PresentedViewController as children.